# Generating Hibernate POJO classes using ANT SCRIPT

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am generating hibernate pojo classes with annotations from existing tables using Ant Script. I am stuck with a problem. Problem is that Generated class contains

```
@Table(name="person", catalog="db1")
public class Person
{
//properties
//getter-setter methods
}
```

and I want to remove catalog="db1" while auto generation. I can remove manually catalog="db1" from code but I dont want that.
How should I write ANT SCRIPT ? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following line in your hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<property name="default_catalog">db1</property>
```

And in hibernate.reveng.xml use

```
<table name="person"></table>
```

Instead of

```
<table catalog="db1" name="person"></table>
```